# Why choose an 8bit over a 32bit MCU

Tags: microcontroller, design, component-selection, bus, cortex-m

With the recent Cortex-M rage, there seems to be a lot of 8bit bashing going around.

I was wondering what specific use cases engineers encountered where 8bit MCUs were the preferred choice over 32bit, and what decisions informed their choice.

I think this information proves useful as an aid for others who need to make a similar choice between 8/32bit.

Comment: Way too opinion based. Voting to close for being too broad.

Comment: I could see a case of that argument.  I am geniunly curious to know the design decision for using 8bit MCUs.  Is there a way I could reword this to make it less broad?

Comment: I know this has been asked and answered before, but I can't find it.

Comment: Do let me know if you find it.  I've tried to find something as well with no success.

Comment: It really depends on the application and how complex the solution needs to be with an 8bit v3 32bit micro all bounded by cost.

Comment: Power, price, simplicity, physical size, backwards compatibility with legacy designs (including firmware), compatibility with existing toolchains, reusing components for lower BOM count and lower BOM cost. The first two reasons especially can be of overriding concern.

Comment: it's all about getting the right tool for the job. sometimes you need a hammer and sometimes you need a construction company.

Comment: http://www.electronicdesign.com/microcontrollers/11-myths-about-8-bit-microcontrollers

Comment: @Trevor: I've updated the wording of the question to get more to the original intent of my question.  Hopefully it will address some of your concerns.

Comment: @BruceAbbott: Thanks for the link.  I think it would be great to collect more articles such as yours, explaining why 8bit can be a good choice for certain designs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was wondering what fellow engineers thought of 8bit MCUs, and why they would consider using one in their design over a 32bit MCU.

I'm a 32-bit guy by trade: worked a lot on earlier LPC and Luminary chips.

For most of what I do personally, I use 8-bit because they are sufficient. actually more than sufficient: many times I have to run the mcus at speed lower than their default speed settings.

8-bit mcus are simple to learn, inexpensive and best of all plentiful.

with that said, there are lots of demanding applications where a simple 8-bit mcu doesn't cut it. Or more precisely, doesn't cut it without serious additional investments in software. If you lots of number crunching, loads of multi-tasking (driving graphics for example), or into some specialized niches.

for what I do personally, 8-bit vs. 32-bit is fully transparent. to the point that I can run most of my 8-bit code on 32-bit, or vice versa, with minimum changes. I can even run my Arduino code on most 16/32bit mcus with minimum changes now.

so most of the time, what I pick on the hardware side is not even driven by software.

edit: as to your broader point of whether the 8-bit market is dying (commercially), I would say, based on my own experience, that it is definitely so.

10+ years or so ago, I was at a software house that offered a full range of support, from 8-bit chips to 32-bit chips. one of the earliest decisions I made was to analyze the profitability of each platform and as a result, we quickly dropped support for 8-bit chips, to the point that we want to get paid to upgrade our older 8-bit software and we provide no support going forward.

8-bit programmers have a hard time finding work and 32-bit programmers are in high demand. you can observe the same trend on the programming side, at embedded conferences. I went to a ST conference on their 32-bit offerings in Shanghai 10 years ago and was absolutely shocked by the many young faces there.

I  think if you are an 8-bit programmer in a high cost area, you better have a niche or two. or you face some serious risks very soon.

Comment: Insights like these are extremely valuable.  Thanks for taking the time to share your thoughts and experience.

Comment: Thanks, dannyf, for your perspective. I don't find much I'd change. 32-bit is expanding its options pell-mell. There are a couple of niches for 8/16 bit -- very low cost is one; SOT23-6 packaging is another (good luck finding a 32-bitter there); low power (find a 32-bit competitor for MSP430 for example); and... well, I can get a *good* 1MHz sample rate 16-bit ADC on an 8-bit core... but do not know of a single case of 32-bit that has one. (I used this last in a product a few years ago.) But sophisticated software libraries make more sense on 32-bit as there is more mem, horsepower, etc.

Comment: there are quite a few 32-bit chips with 16 (or higher) adcs. the F3 series from ST, and Freescale for example.

Comment: Low power offerings are expanding as well. some M0+ will go below 100us/Mhz. But no one has been able to beat MSP430 on instant start. But I'm not sure there is a big mkt for that -> that's really for ultra-lower power consumption.

Comment: there is no mkt for low cost design jobs in most developed countries, as such end-use products with such devices have moved overseas for manufacturing. so i don't think that's a niche that anyone wants to play in. life is tough there.